# How long should a brief CV for a call for papers be?

Tags: conference, cv, call-for-papers

I have seen in some call for papers for conferences request a brief CV together with an abstract.

Most call for papers I've seen in the Humanities (my field is history) usually look for a 250-300 word abstract.

Slightly a side note, but when a PhD student or Early Career researcher submitting that may not have much to put in a CV, is there a different format for a "brief CV" or not?

I am wondering what is expected in the "brief CV" requested and how long it is expected to be?

Comment: I think this would be perfectly a good question here - but currently there is just too little information to be answered with certainty. Could you perhaps add field information, and perhaps a bit more information about what kind of call for paper this is (for a non-archival conference, workshop, funding opportunity, etc)?

Comment: My instinct is probably a one-paragraph biography - such that it might be published in a book of abstracts along with the abstract. However, this is guesswork, and the only way you'll find out for sure i sto write to the conference organiser and ask them.

Comment: @Flyto Some call for papers specific if they want a short biography in the manner you state, others ask for a brief CV which is different. There should be no need to ask the organiser of the conference which they want.

Comment: @gman indeed, in an ideal world there should be no need because the CFP would tell you. However, presumably it hasn't told you, or you wouldn't be asking this question, and people here can only guess. So the only way you can find out the correct answer is to ask the organiser.

Comment: @Flyto Should be no need to guess, my question says the cfp includes a request for a brief CV. What I was asking is how long that brief CV should be, assuming the term means you don't send in a full CV.

Comment: @gman and what I'm saying is that "brief CV" could mean anything from a paragraph to a page, and the only way to know for sure is to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is more than a page it is too long. As for what should be there, say something about your education, current employment and some of your publications. It isn't necessary to be comprehensive but include things that are most relevant to the conference and to the paper you are submitting.

That is probably about enough, but if it seems too short, include honors, etc. if you like.

All the committee is looking for at this point is that you are qualified to say what you want to say in the resulting paper. Focus on that above all.